# XElemenet AddAfterSelf not adding to last node

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

Code that creates XML:

```
 public static string TagInvoice()
    {                             
        string InvoiceAll = "";

        foreach (var item in QueryDb.ListaPostavkRacuna)
        {

            XElement Invoice = new XElement("Invoice",
                                           new XElement("Identification",
                                               new XElement("Structure", item.Structure),
                                               new XElement("NrStructure", item.NrStructure)),
                                           new XElement("ItemsDesc",
                                               new XElement("DESC",
                                                    new XElement("DESC1","some_value"),
                                                    new XElement("DESC2", "ordinary"))));


            for (int i = 1; i <= (int)Math.Ceiling(item.item_desc.Length / 35d); i++)
            {

                int Max = 35,
                    Min = 35 * i - Max;

                if (item.item_desc.Length >= (Min + Max))
                {
                    Min = Max * i - Max;
                }
                else
                {
                    Max = item.item_desc.Length - (i - 1) * 35;
                    Min = (i - 1) * 35;
                }

                        XElement TempItemDesc = new XElement("ItemsDesc",
                                                       new XElement("Code", item.code_art),
                                                       new XElement("DESC",
                                                       new XElement("DESC1", item.item_desc.Substring(Min, Max))));

                        Invoice.Element("ItemsDesc").AddAfterSelf(TempItemDesc);
            }

            InvoiceAll = InvoiceAll.ToString() + Invoice.ToString();
        }

        return InvoiceAll;
    }
```

If you look closely you will see i am dividing large string into smaller onces with max `35 length`.
Those smaller **strings** are then incorporated into **TempItemDesc** and added to  **XElement Invoice.**

Problem is in order of those **added** elements. Looks like that The **AddAfterSelf** method is taking into account only 
first (originial) <**ItemsDesc**> so my nodes are added in incorrect order (see below):

Example:

```
String = "A B C D"
```

Nodes should be added like:

```
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
```

They are added:

```
"D"
"C"
"B"
"A"
```

Is this expected behaveour, how can i add my nodes to the list in a corret order?

Comment: It's the `Element(...)` method which is returning the **first** element with the given name as [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.Element);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). You can try `Invoice.Elements("ItemsDesc").Last()` instead.

Comment: It looks to me like `Invoice.Add(TempItemDesc)` would do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in MSDN,

> AddAfterSelf, adds the specified content immediately after current node.

You are adding the node after first node.
Try this code:

```
Invoice.Element("ItemsDesc").Last().AddAfterSelf(TempItemDesc);
```

Related link: [XNode.AddAfterSelf Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.xml.linq.xnode.addafterself(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Given that the last `ItemDesc` is the end of the element's content, `Invoice.Add(TempItemDesc)` is equivalent here.

Comment: If i use Invoice.Add the next XElement will be added inside current <ItemsDesc> tag which is not what i am looking for. I need to add it after...

Comment: @rayrayroy your solution works. There is a small typo in your answer its Elements instead of Element. Thank you.

Comment: @Tagyoureit not it won't? It would be added *inside* `ItemsDesc` if you called `Add` on an `ItemsDesc` element. `Invoice.Add` will add as the last child node of `Invoice` which is precisely what you want to do. See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nUzjwL).